# neovim-qt : Is it possible open files in the existing window?

Tags: neovim-qt

When I open a file (either from dolphin or terminal) a window of nvim-qt is created.
Is there a way to open the file in the existing nvim-qt window and raise/focus to the window?

Note: I know there is a way for gvim using silent server option, but couldn't make that work with nvim-qt.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to [neovim Wiki FAQ](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ) and [Issue #1750](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1750), client-server / remote feature was removed in Neovim.

Instead, [neovim-remote](https://github.com/mhinz/neovim-remote) can be used.  After installing it (`pip3 install neovim-remote`), launch `nvim` like:

```
$ NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS=/tmp/nvimsocket nvim
```

And open files remotely

```
$ nvr --remote file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
:args /path/to/file.name
```